# install4j URL handlers always launches new instance

Tags: install4j

The documentation for URL handlers says:

> ... Subsequent invocations ... can be intercepted with com.install4j.api.launcher.StartupNotification

But actually a new instance is always launched unless the "Allow only a single running instance of the application" is set for the launcher.

Is this as intended? Am I doing something wrong?

It kind of makes sense that it would work like this since if more than one instance is running, which should be used? But it does contradict the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the intended behavior. I will fix the documentation.